# How to display the images in this vector?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to display the images in this vector? Take a look at the xaml and C# codes in order to see what I've tried with no result.

```
            byte[] pngBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@".\GalleryImages");
            List<WineModel> images = new List<WineModel>();
            images.Add(new WineModel(pngBytes, "this is a description"));

            var button = new KinectTileButton
            {
               Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pngBytes),

               Background = images[0].image

           };
```

Code xaml:

```
<WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
            <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="1" Click="KinectTileButton_Click" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="2"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="3"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="4"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="5" Click="KinectTileButton_Click_1" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="6"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="7"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="8"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="9"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="10"/>
            <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
        </WrapPanel>
```

If I had to display them in an imagebox the code would look like this but I don't know how 
to adjust it for my xaml code.

```
pictureBox1.Image = images[0].Image;
```

EDIT:

```
  public class WineModel
{
    public WineModel(string[] bytes, string description)
    {
        this.Bytes = bytes;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    public string[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: byte[] pngBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@".\GalleryImages"); looks like you read a folder not a file. In WPF you usually don't load images manually. You can use string paths or BitmapImage.

Comment: This is what I should change, right?  "string[] pngBytes = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");"

Comment: Yes. And then for each file name you will have to create a KinectTileButton I suppose.

Comment: ok, i understand that but how do I give each image a different description? i've attached above, the code from the "windemodel" class in order to make it clear.. what i want is to make a different description for each image

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to combine an image file and a description. You can for example for each image file (img.png) associate a text file (img.png.txt). Personnaly I don't like this solution because it depends on file system and file names.

Another way is to use integrated .Net xml serialization capabilities. All you have to do is to create an xml file with cuples of values (filePath, desctiption).

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Library>
  <Thumbs>
    <Thumb>
      <ImagePath>./Images/img1.png</ImagePath>
      <Description>Description for the image 1</Description>
    </Thumb>
    <Thumb>
      <ImagePath>./Images/img2.png</ImagePath>
      <Description>Description for the image 2</Description>
    </Thumb>
    <Thumb>
      <ImagePath>./Images/img3.png</ImagePath>
      <Description>Description for the image 3</Description>
    </Thumb>
  </Thumbs>
</Library>
```

Then you define the corresponding # classes. Be careful class/property names should be the same as in the xml file:

```
public class Library
{
    public List<Thumb> Thumbs { get; set; }
}

public class Thumb
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now all you need is to call XmlSerializer class to read the xml and automatically fill out Library structure.

```
public Library DeserializeLibrary(string path)
{
    Library result;

    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Library));

    // To read the file, create a FileStream.
    using (FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
        result = (Library)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Now when you call DeserializeLibrary("Library.xml") it will return Library class instance filled out with 3 instances of Thumb.

Some links about C# serialization: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.90).aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.90).aspx

PS: I expressely avoided to adopt my code to your particular class names. I think you have everything to finish writing your code.